# Verificar se página vem do Google?

Tags: php, google

Boa Noite

Como posso fazer via PHP para descobrir se o usuário veio do Google e qual palavra chave foi digitada? Assim, quando ele se cadastra no meu site, posso verificar de onde ele veio e palavra quem encontrou o site.

Obrigada

Answer (score 1):

É possível apenas verificar se proveio de um dos domínios do Google.

Um exemplo simples com PHP é ler a variável global `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`.

No entanto, não é possível obter os termos da busca pela URL de referência porque os termos são codificados. A codificação combina com códigos únicos do usuário, ou seja, quando **fulano** busca por "*algo*" vai gerar uma string `GVhao390#` mas se **beltrano** buscar a mesma palavra, retornará uma string diferente `6%U9*8Ed`. A chave está no parâmetro `ved`.

Um dos motivos em codificar os termos é devido a questões de privacidade dos usuários.

Para obter os dados de referências de buscas, utilize o [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools) e [Google Analytics](https://analytics.google.com).

- <sub>*As string codificadas são meramente ilustrativas*</sub>

Comment: Obrigada. Mas essa var vem vazia, quando clico no meu site pelo Google. Muito estranho...

Comment: Isso é normal. HTTP_REFERER pode retornar vazio exporadicamente. Nesses casos não há muito o que fazer. Mas se retornar sempre vazio em tudo, então pode ter algum problema. Nesse caso verifique as configurações do ambiente (a sua máquina local ou o seu provedor de hospedagem).